# Database conection pentaho a oracle (no conecta)

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, conexión, pentaho

Necesito hacer una conexión desde pentaho a Oracle, pero no he podido, luego de poner la información requerida (localhost, puerto 1521 con el usuario SYSTEM), me figura el siguiente mensaje:

```
Connection failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
ORA-12505: No se puede conectar a la base de datos: el SID %s no está registrado con el listener en %s. (CONNECTION_ID=0vp13A9rROWU9oVghFPVLQ==)
```

En data base connection, selecciono General - Oracle - Native (JDBC) y luego ingreso todos los datos para la conexión. En la carpeta lib de pentaho pegué el `jdbc-oracle.jar`, la conexión en Oracle está correcta, pero en pentaho no se conecta, también he intentado con el Oracle RBD, pero me sale otro error:

```
Driver class 'oracle.rdb.jdbc.rdbThin.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'Oracle RDB' driver (jar file) is installed.
oracle.rdb.jdbc.rdbThin.Driver
```

He buscado por todos lados ese jar, pero nada

```
Pentaho (spoon)
Version: 9.3

Oracle IDE  22.2.1.234.1810 (21c)
Plataforma Java(TM) 11.0.16.1
Soporte de Control de Versiones 22.2.1.234.1810
```

De antemano, muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda que puedan dar.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Creo que haría falta añadir a la pregunta cuales son exactamente _todos los datos para la conexión_ que estás agregando. (recuerda nada más no publicar contraseñas, sustituir por otro texto que deje claro si se agrega).